# Passing two arrays as arguments VBA

Tags: arrays, vba, csv

I am trying to read a CSV file and split strings into columns of sheet.

So the program reads the CSV, then reads the string (getting the string position and length) and then output the results to the columns.

I did make a macro that does this, but I now want to do this using arrays, which I was not using before, but cant seem to pass the arrays as arguments to the SplitColumns function.

So the string spec is like "start pos, end pos, format", but for now I am not using the format.

Could you help me? I think this might a super simple issue, i am just stuck on this for the last hour.

```
    Option Explicit

    Public Sub ConvertPanel()

        Dim convertFile As Long, i As Long, y As Long
        Dim specString As String

        Dim a As Variant
        Dim b As Variant
        Dim c As Range

        Set c = Worksheets(1).Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(1, 1))

        specString = "1,10,@|11,2,@|15,1,@|16,4,@|20,2,@|23,1,@|31,1,@|35,1,@|39,1,@|41,1,@|160,1,@|161,2,@|163,1,@|165,1,@|25,2,@|29,2,@|34,1"

        a = QuickRead("file.txt")
        b = ConvertSpecString(specString)


    End Sub

    Private Function ConvertSpecString(ByVal specString As String) As String()

            Dim fieldsInfo() As String
            Dim inputString As String

            inputString = Replace(specString, Space(1), vbNullString)
            fieldsInfo = Split(inputString, "|")
            ConvertSpecString = fieldsInfo

    End Function

    Private Function QuickRead(ByVal fileName As String) As String()

        Dim fileNumber As Long
        Dim stringRes As String
        Dim fileSize As Long
        Dim v As Variant

        fileNumber = FreeFile
        fileSize = FileLen(fileName)
        stringRes = Space(fileSize)

        Open fileName For Binary Access Read As #fileNumber
            Get #fileNumber, , stringRes
        Close fileNumber

        QuickRead = Split(stringRes, vbCrLf)

    End Function

    Private Function SplitColumns(ByRef lineArray() As Variant, ByRef fieldsInfo() As Variant, ByVal StartCell As Range) As Variant

        Dim indexLine As Long
        Dim indexCount As Long
        Dim stringRange As String
        Dim stringColumn As Long
        Dim fileInfo As String

        stringRange = StartCell
        stringColumn = startCell.Column

            For indexCount = LBound(lineArray) To UBound(lineArray)

                stringColumn = stringRange.Column
                fileInfo = Split(fieldsInfo(indexCount), ",")
                stringRange.EntireRow.Cells(1, stringColumn).Value = Mid(lineArray(indexCount), CLng(fileInfo(0)), CLng(fileInfo(1)))
                stringColumn = stringColumn + 1

            Next indexCount


    End Function
```

Comment: The problem is saying: lineArray() As Variant, you need to pass a variant:    lineArray As Variant (which will be a 2D array) or an array:   lineArray() As string/long/double

Comment: Thank you, that actually solved the issue! You should submit an answer so I can guive you the points you deserve!  @tompreston

Comment: I wasn't sure this would fully answer, but glad it helped, I've written it up below, the linked site is quite helpful for this too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a decent tutorial about this here: http://www.cpearson.com/excel/vbaarrays.htm

Essentially with a Variant if you want to pass a variant to a function you should use the syntax:

```
Private Function SplitColumns(ByRef lineArray As Variant, ByRef fieldsInfo As Variant, ByVal StartCell As Range) As Variant
```

To Pass an array you can use the syntax:

```
Private Function SplitColumns(ByRef lineArray() As String, ByRef fieldsInfo() As Double, ByVal StartCell As Range) As Variant
```

But you can't pass a Variable like this:

```
ByRef lineArray() As Variant
```

Good luck with the project.